# LaTeX: use different fonts in math mode

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to use two different fonts in math mode. Concretely, I would like to use uppercase letters of font Palatino to give names to matrices, leaving the rest in Computer modern, so that matrices have their own style. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite good an idea: Palatino and Computer Modern don't mix at all visually and it would be very hard for the reader to discriminate between an "A" in CM and an "A" in Palatino.

[image: Here's a comparison]

In my opinion there aren't sufficient visual clues to distinguish the two fonts.

Here are the necessary macros, anyway:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpal}{OT1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathpal}{bold}{OT1}{ppl}{b}{n}
```

After giving these in the preamble, you can use `\mathpal` (or the name you choose) to access letters in Palatino.

Comment: Grazie per la celere risposta, i comandi fanno esattamente quello che stavo cercando. Comunque, la mia idea non era cambiare il carattere per distinguere le lettere maiuscole con cui chiamo le matrici da altre maiuscole, ma solo alleggerire un po' il documento con un nuovo carattere. Se effettivamente il risultato non fosse quello sperato, sostituirò Palatino con un altro. Grazie ancora per il prezioso aiuto!

Comment: It's better to write in English, here. I don't think many people, other than the two of us, will understand your message. `:-)`

Comment: OK :) then, thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SX! Benvenuto su TeX.SX! [C'è un forum in lingua italiana, se ancora non lo conosci](http://www.guit.sssup.it/phpbb/index.php). For the non Italian speaking people: [there's a forum in Italian](http://www.guit.sssup.it/phpbb/index.php)

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it, I just thought it would've been more probable to get an answer on a forum in English, with more people around... '^^